# insert, update, delete statements in a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables: Persons, Person_Categories and Persons_PersonCategories which is a linking table for a n:m relationship.

I've also written the following query, but the insert statement doesn't work correctly. Insert, update and delete are separate statements. The error message I get is "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

```
SELECT Persons_PersonCategories.PersonID, PrsCategory
FROM Person_Categories
INNER JOIN Persons_PersonCategories
ON Persons_PersonCategories.PrsCatID = Person_Categories.PrsCatID

INSERT INTO Persons_PersonCategories
VALUES (:PrsCategory)

UPDATE Persons_PersonCategories
SET Persons_PersonCategories.PrsCatID = :PrsCatID
WHERE Person_Categories.PrsCatID = :OLD PrsCatID
AND Persons.PersonID = :OLD PersonID

DELETE FROM Persons_PersonCategories
WHERE Person_Categories.PrsCatID = :PrsCatID
AND Persons.PersonID = :PersonID;
```

Any help will be appreciated,
zan

Comment: you may have to specify column list in your insert statement, ex: insert into table (col1, col2) values (:val1,:val2)

Comment: State your table schema please.

Comment: This does not look like one query. Rather, it looks like four separate statements.

Comment: What does *"doesn't work correctly"* mean?  Is there an error message?  (If so, what is it?)  Is the resulting data surprising to you in some way?  (If so, what precisely did you do, what precisely was the result, and what precisely did you expect to be different?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the column being updated:

```
INSERT INTO Persons_PersonCategories (PrsCategory) VALUES (:PrsCategory)
```

Substitute the correct column name in place of `PrsCategory` if I have not guessed correctly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add the PersonID

```
INSERT INTO Persons_PersonCategories(PersonID, PrsCatID)
VALUES (:PersonID, :PrsCatID)
```